# Get Individual Posts from Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am fairly new to php and what I can't figure out is how to pass an id to my article.php page and retrieve that specific information from the corresponding row on the page. On my homepage I have retrieved an array of information so as to only display a certain number of recent posts. What I have for this is:

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {

$id[]=$row['id'];
$title[]=$row['title'];
$description[]=$row['description'];
$image[]=$row['imagename'];

}
```

I am getting the specific information in a div with this content:

```
<h4><?php print $title[0] ?></h4>
<p><?php print $description[0] ?></p>
<p id="moreLink" class="pull-right"><a href="article.php?id=<?php echo $id[0] ?>">Read More</a></p>
```

My question is how can I pass the specific id that is clicked to my article.php and get that information? Or is there a better way to do what I am doing now? I've tried using the $_GET method but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's just say:

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
// $id is int, so there's no need to escape it
$retrieved_post_query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=$id";
$retrieved_post = mysql_query($retrieved_post_query);
```

Comment: and be prone to sql injection.

Comment: He's just asking for the basics. unless he states otherwise.

Comment: So this would be for the article.php page correct? And where would there be security issues?

Comment: And thank you very much, it worked for me. I think my mistake was putting the $id variable in quotes in my query.

Comment: Yep, since article.php is the receiving end. and yes, there are security issues, because it's just basic PHP/MYSQL interaction. but in the perspective of getting the individual posts, it will certainly get the job done.

Comment: I'd recommend using mysqli, and at _least_ mysqli_real_escape_string() (the 'i' in 'mysqli' stands for improved, much better functions that work pretty much like the old ones do).

Comment: It is enough to make sure id is integer